# Is there a special specific term for someone who travels to other multiverses willingly?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, I have this made up character, who has this secret job where he and his crew travel to other multiverses and alternative realities and collects samples and specimens for scientists to research.

While this character is obviously not real, is there a specific term in English that basically means “someone/people who travel(s) to other multiverses willingly”?

The closest thing I could find was a term in German called “попаданец”, but it’s meant for someone traveling unwillingly to other universes.

Comment: I suppose you already have a word for one who does this _unwillingly_ (otherwise why would you ask). What do you have already? That would help. Also, I'm pretty sure 'попаданец' is not German, except in only one universe the one where... OMG...

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the English language had such a term, since we don't know that there is a multiverse and we have no evidence of people being able to travel outside of this universe (willingly or otherwise).

Comment: Ask Rick from Rick and Morty :)

Comment: We have words for things that may or may not exist. "Multiverse", "vampire", "zombie" and "teleporter" are just a few examples.

Comment: [Dimensional Traveler:](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DimensionalTraveler) A dimensional traveler is any character who can (more or less) freely travel between various planes of existence, like parallel universes, etc

Comment: -naut is used for similar meanings; astronaut, cosmonaut, etc; [chrononaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrononaut) is sometimes used for time traveller. It's a shame cosmonaut is already in use.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the word requested for the scenario described by the OP is so unusual and bizarre for it to be useful to anyone else but the OP themself.

Comment: You could argue *acid head*, but you may be using a different definition of *travel* and *multiverse*.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for the word "Sliders". 
To be fair it was only used in (and the title of) a TV Show back in 1995 but it fit your description perfectly.

On the  [Sliders' Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders) the protagonists are defined as:

> A group of travelers who use wormholes to "slide" between different parallel universes

Comment: please add a source to support your answer